# send password to server with angular 2

Tags: angular, passwords

I am working with Angular 2 rc1 to create a login form.
These examples send the password via angular's http inside a header. But ain't that dangerous for hackers? I do have a SSL certificate.

1. https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt
2. https://auth0.com/blog/2015/05/14/creating-your-first-real-world-angular-2-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api-and-everything-in-between/

Comment: your second link is broken: Sorry, but the page you are looking for does not exist.

Comment: @AngJobs I fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Https (SSL) connection is the way you make it hard to hack. It ensures the connection is secured so you can send user's password and not worry about it.

Answer (score -3):

If we don't full trust transmision chanel (we know that a secure SSL connection is not obvious, and the attempt to impersonate a trusted SSL certificates happen to) then:

I suggest add additional protection, taken advantage of encryption on browser-side transferred data like: username/password, using asynchronous algorithm (I recommend the library SJCL) and key pair generating on the backend side (Webservice)

Comment: If you don't trust SSL, how do you transfer your secret your additional encryption is based on from the back-end to the front-end?

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, and you have right we should assume that we have a secure transmission channel, but when we have attack like "man in the middle" we can try to make it more difficult for attacks such cases. But shure this is not full solution what I am suggested. I thing we must wait for solution provided by suppliers browsers.